# Java code to display expiration date of certificates in a Java KeyStore

Tags: java

Looking for java code to display expiration date of certificates in a given keystore.

What i am expecting is below output after running the java code:

CerticateName: 
CertificateExpirationDate: 
NumberOfDaysLeft:

## Update

I have come up with the code below, Which print certificate alias, I am interested in Expriation date

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class sslcertslist {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("MyKeystore.jks");
    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    String password = "MyPassword";
    keystore.load(is, password.toCharArray());

    Enumeration e = keystore.aliases();
    for (; e.hasMoreElements();) {
      String alias = (String) e.nextElement();

      boolean b = keystore.isKeyEntry(alias);

      b = keystore.isCertificateEntry(alias);
      System.out.println(alias);
    }
    is.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: SO is more a site to help you when you're stuck, not write the code for you. Give it a shot or try Googling a bit harder :)

Comment: You might have a look at http://keystore-explorer.org/. But SO isn't the right place to ask question like this. If you want to code it yourself, then you should post the code you have and explain what's not working as expected.

Comment: I have come here googling for a way to find the expiry date for certificates in a Java keystore and the question and answer were both helpful to me +1!

Comment: I am glad that it helped you @mxro

Answer (score 17):

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableEntryException;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class GetSslcertsExpires {

public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

 try {
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keystore.load(new FileInputStream("/DemoTrust.jks"), "DemoTrustKeyStorePassPhrase".toCharArray());
        Enumeration aliases = keystore.aliases();
        for(; aliases.hasMoreElements();) {
            String alias = (String) aliases.nextElement();
            Date certExpiryDate = ((X509Certificate) keystore.getCertificate(alias)).getNotAfter();
            SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            //Tue Oct 17 06:02:22 AEST 2006
            Date today = new Date();
            long dateDiff = certExpiryDate.getTime() - today.getTime();
            long expiresIn = dateDiff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            System.out.println("Certifiate: " + alias + "\tExpires On: " + certExpiryDate + "\tFormated Date: " + ft.format(certExpiryDate) + "\tToday's Date: " + ft.format(today) + "\tExpires In: "+ expiresIn);
        }
    }

catch (Exception e)
     {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

- Sample Output
  [image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Please note that in Java class names are given in camel case and a leading capital letter such as `SslCertsExpiryDates`. Variable names usually begin with a lower-case letter such as `dateDiff`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggesting this, I followed bad coding practice :D @mxro

Comment: i got the below error , when trying to get the expiry details of my JKS file , how to handle this ?
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed

Comment: looks like your password provided when loading the keystore is wrong.

Comment: In Java 9 up (since Oct 2017) you can call `KeyStore.getInstance` directly on a `File` (and pw) thus skipping the `.load` call and `FileInputStream`

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another solution

```
public static Date getSimpleCertExpiryDate(String pfxFileName, String pfxPassword) throws KeyStoreException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keystore.load(new FileInputStream(pfxFileName), pfxPassword.toCharArray());
    Enumeration<?> aliases = keystore.aliases();
    Date expiryDate = null;

    for (; aliases.hasMoreElements();) {
        String alias = (String) aliases.nextElement();
        expiryDate = ((X509Certificate) keystore.getCertificate(alias)).getNotAfter();
    }
    return expiryDate;
}
```

Output be Expiry Date (e.g.) as Tue Mar 16 11:03:25 IST 2021
You can use this to check against today's date