# Read a JKS file from AWS S3 bucket and check expiration date of certificate?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, certificate, jks

I need to implement functionality for a spring boot project that reads JKS files from an S3 bucket and checks expiration dates for certificates and use a cron job to check and send alerts when certificates are X days or weeks away from expiring.

I'm able to get the file in memory as a byte array. That's pretty much as far as it goes. Since the keystore isn't serializable I can't really do anything with it... I'm just stuck with a byte array.

Any takers...? Lemme see ya flex them programmammatic skillzors :)

Comment: I'm sure there are Java libraries for reading/writing JKS files. There's even a [Python package](https://pypi.org/project/pyjks/) for this. There's also an AWS blog post on [monitoring expiring certificates in ACM](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-monitor-expirations-of-imported-certificates-in-aws-certificate-manager-acm/) that may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The KeyStore class has a [load()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#load(java.io.InputStream,%20char%5B%5D)) method that takes an InputStream. You can wrap a byte array in a [ByteArrayInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html).

You should be able to load a KeyStore from a byte array like this:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
ks.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(myByteArray), myKeystorePassword);
```

You should be able to follow the solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838084/java-code-to-display-expiration-date-of-certificates-in-a-java-keystore) to then check the expiration date(s).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        ks.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(myByteArray), keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
        Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();
        for(; aliases.hasMoreElements();) {
            String alias = (String) aliases.nextElement();
            Date certExpiryDate = ((X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias)).getNotAfter();
            System.out.println("certExpiryDate = " + certExpiryDate);}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).